# How do I make a function in R with a mass amount of code?

Tags: r, function

I think this is a fairly basic question, as I am a new R user, but I want to make it so that I can activate the entire code below with a single entry/word (I presumed it would be a function). If this has already been asked, I apologize, and please refer me to the link where it is answered. Thank you in advance for all help.
My code:

```
head(yelp, 10)
str(yelp)
yelp_flat<- flatten(yelp)
str(yelp_flat)
library(tibble)
yelp_tbl <- as_data_frame(yelp_flat)
yelp_tbl
yelp_tbl$newcolumn <- NULL
yelp_tbl$newcolumn1 <- NULL
yelp_tbl$shotClock <- NULL
yelp_tbl$period <- NULL
yelp_tbl$wallClock <- NULL
yelp_tbl$gameClock <- NULL
yelp_tbl$gameClockStopped <- NULL
yelp_tbl$ball <- NULL
head(yelp_tbl)
good <- unnest(yelp_tbl) #extracts xyz from original dataframe
library(tidyr)
player <- good %>% separate(xyz, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
finish <- player %>% separate(xyz1, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
k <- finish %>% separate(player_x, c("trash", "player_x"), sep = "c")
k$trash <- NULL
r <- k %>% separate(player_z, c("player_z", "tra"), sep = "\\)")
u <- r %>% separate(player_x, c("kol", "player_x"), sep = "\\(")
Away_Team <- u
Away_Team$garbage <- NULL
Away_Team$playerId1<- NULL
Away_Team$aplayer_x <- NULL
Away_Team$aplayer_y <- NULL
Away_Team$aplayer_z <- NULL
Away_Team$dispose <- NULL
Away_Team$brack <- NULL
Away_Team$kol <- NULL
Away_Team$tra <- NULL
View(Away_Team)
yelp_tbl
yelp_tbl$newcolumn <- NULL
yelp_tbl$newcolumn1 <- NULL
yelp_tbl$shotClock <- NULL
yelp_tbl$period <- NULL
yelp_tbl$wallClock <- NULL
yelp_tbl$gameClock <- NULL
yelp_tbl$gameClockStopped <- NULL
yelp_tbl$ball <- NULL
head(yelp_tbl)
good <- unnest(yelp_tbl) #extracts xyz from original dataframe
library(tidyr)
player <- good %>% separate(xyz, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
finish <- player %>% separate(xyz1, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
k <- finish %>% separate(player_x, c("trash", "player_x"), sep = "c")
k$trash <- NULL
r <- k %>% separate(player_z, c("player_z", "tra"), sep = "\\)")
u <- r %>% separate(player_x, c("kol", "player_x"), sep = "\\(")
Home_Team <- u
Home_Team$garbage <- NULL
Home_Team$playerId1<- NULL
Home_Team$hplayer_x <- NULL
Home_Team$hplayer_y <- NULL
Home_Team$hplayer_z <- NULL
Home_Team$dispose <- NULL
Home_Team$brack <- NULL
Home_Team$kol <- NULL
Home_Team$tra <- NULL
View(Home_Team)
View (Away_Team)
Table <- rbind(Home_Team, Away_Team)
View(Table) #order frameIdx to see correct order
```

Comment: Yes, a function - you should specify which part about making a function has you stumped; since there are lots of resources out there that describe how to do that if you search how to make a function in R.

Comment: Could you add some usable data (copy and paste in R) to try to help you? However you can read [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).

Comment: This code, when run, generates a table based on a json file I have previously streamed in. I am trying to simplify this code to a simple word or function so that my code is more compact. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

So, indeed you should make a function. Here are some steps to follow:

**1. Put all your code in your function**

```
my_function <- function(){
   # Your code
}
```

**2. Identify what you have as an input** (aka, what your are not building in your code), they will become the argument of your function

```
my_function <- function(arg1, arg2, ...){
   # Your code
}
```

In your example, I identified `yelp`

**3. Identify what you want to output** (ideally only one object), they will be in the `return` of your function

```
my_function <- function(arg1, arg2, ...){
  # Your code
  return(output)
}
```

In your example I identified `Table`

**4. Take all the import/library and put them outside your function**

```
library(lib1)
my_function <- function(arg1, arg2, ...){
  # Your code
  return(output)
}
```

EDIT using @r2evans suggestion: Using `library`is generally used instead of `require`, [here](https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/) and [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) is some literature on it.
In your code I identified `tidyr` and `tibble`

**5. Identify what you want to print**/View and what was just for debugging. Add a print to print, suppres what you don't want

**6. Add some comments/slice your code**

For example I would add something like `# Creating XXX table`

**7. Improve code quality**

You should try to minimize the number of line of code (for example using loops and avoiding code to be in double). Make variables names explicit (instead of k, u, r...)

Regarding loop, in your code you drop some columns on at a time, you could do a loop to drop them in order. (It's what I have done bellow). It helps to make your code easier to read/debug. In this particular case, as Gregor said it is heaven faster to drop them all at once with using a list of column names (if you are interested check his comment).

---

**Here you go:**

There are still some improvement to do especially regarding point number 7 and 5.

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

yelp_function <- function(yelp){
  # Printing the input
  print(head(yelp, 10))
  print(str(yelp))

  # Flatten table
  yelp_flat<- flatten(yelp)
  print(str(yelp_flat))

  # Create yelp_tbl and drop some columns
  yelp_tbl <- as_data_frame(yelp_flat)
  # Drop some columns
  for (col in c("newcolumn", "newcolumn1", "shotClock", "period", "wallClock", "gameClock", "gameClockStopped", "ball")){
    yelp_tbl[, col] <- NULL
  }

  print(head(yelp_tbl))

  # Build some table
  good <- unnest(yelp_tbl) #extracts xyz from original dataframe
  player <- good %>% separate(xyz, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
  finish <- player %>% separate(xyz1, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
  k <- finish %>% separate(player_x, c("trash", "player_x"), sep = "c")
  k$trash <- NULL
  r <- k %>% separate(player_z, c("player_z", "tra"), sep = "\\)")
  u <- r %>% separate(player_x, c("kol", "player_x"), sep = "\\(")

  # Build away team
  Away_Team <- u

  # Build yelp table: I'm not quite sure why you are rebdoing that... Is this code necessary?
  yelp_tbl
  # Drop some columns
  for (col in c("newcolumn", "newcolumn1", "shotClock", "period", "wallClock", "gameClock", "gameClockStopped", "ball")){
    yelp_tbl[, col] <- NULL
  }

  print(head(yelp_tbl))
  good <- unnest(yelp_tbl) #extracts xyz from original dataframe

  # Build some table
  player <- good %>% separate(xyz, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
  finish <- player %>% separate(xyz1, c("player_x", "player_y", "player_z"), sep = ",")
  k <- finish %>% separate(player_x, c("trash", "player_x"), sep = "c")
  k$trash <- NULL
  r <- k %>% separate(player_z, c("player_z", "tra"), sep = "\\)")
  u <- r %>% separate(player_x, c("kol", "player_x"), sep = "\\(")

  ## Build home_team
  Home_Team <- u

  # Drop some columns
  for (col in c("garbage", "playerId1", "aplayer_x", "aplayer_y", "aplayer_z", "dispose", "brack", "kol", "tra")){
    Away_Team[, col] <- NULL
    Home_Team[, col] <- NULL
  }

  # Merge
  Table <- rbind(Home_Team, Away_Team)

  # Return
  return(Table)
}

View(Table) #order frameIdx to see correct order
```

**Run it:**

To run your code you now just have to execute the function with the needed argument:

```
yelp_function(yelp)
```

---

**NB 1:** please note that I didn't tested the code since you didn't provide data to run it. To improve your question you should give some data using `dput`function.

**NB 2:** There is always room for improvement in the code so you might want to go further and llok into refactoring to avoid having code in double. Control your inputs with some sanity check...

Comment: In the "code improvement" category, setting `data$column <- NULL` does not create a new empty column. In fact, `data$column <- NULL` is commonly recommended as a way to delete a column. So unless all those columns already exist and need deleting, those lines of code are doing nothing and should be removed.

Comment: Yep, wrong comment i will change it. I think he is deleting columns.

Comment: In that case, better to do it all at once with a character vector of column names (and no for loop): `cols_to_drop = c("newcolumn", "newcolumn1", "shotClock", "period", ...)`, then `data[, cols_to_drop] <- list(NULL)` removes them all at once.

Comment: I agree, but since he is a beginner I think starting by for loop is more pedagogic.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I run into a problem however near the end of the code. This is the error message I receive: Error in View : object 'Table' not found
> Table <- rbind(Home_Team, Away_Team)
Error in rbind(Home_Team, Away_Team) : object 'Home_Team' not found

Comment: I apologize, I don't know how to format code in comments

Comment: Sure no problem, if you want me to check what I have done, please give me a sample of table `yelp` using `dput` function

Comment: Since this is essentially a tutorial on R and you think about suggesting `require()` instead of `library()`, two suggestions: (1) don't, the use of `require` here is wrong; and (2) link to some good discussions about their differences. I suggest http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/ and http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html as good reading for why `require` is *rarely* (and definitely not here) useful over `library`.

Comment: You are right, I don't know why i wrote require... Changed it and I added your links.

Answer (score -1):

It's rather simple.

You do this:

```
foo <- function{
   #all your code goes here
}
```

Then you call your function by typing (in console for instance):

```
foo()
```

Comment: For an R noob, this isn't a helpful answer. There is no explanation of arguments, etc.

Comment: For my established data, what do I put into foo()? I am not trying to output a value, but I am trying to output a table with the selected code